# cusrf without cookie and session for an API node api application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to configure the csurf node module for an API that does not use the cookie and session, but it has bearer token authentication.

Below is the code that is what i tried. When i run the below code and getting the below error

```
Error: misconfigured csrf
    at csrf (/Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/csurf/index.js:71:19)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/saravanan/Documents/Development/nodejs/csurf-demo-1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

** Code Snippet **

```
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express')


var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// create express app
var app = express();

app.use(csrf());

// parse cookies
// we need this because "cookie" is true in csrfProtection


app.get('/form', function (req, res) {
  // pass the csrfToken to the view
  res.render('send', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})

app.post('/process', parseForm, function (req, res) {
  res.send('data is being processed')
});

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

When I try with the below code that looks up for the header to validate the token, i am getting the error as cannot read session of undefined.

```
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express')

// setup route middlewares
var csrfProtection = csrf({
    value: (req) => {
        var csrfToken = req.body._csrf || req.headers["x-csrf-token"];
        return csrfToken;
    },
    cookie: false
})
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// create express app
var app = express();

app.use(csrfProtection());

app.get('/form', function (req, res) {
  // pass the csrfToken to the view
  // res.sendStatus(200);
  res.render('send', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})

app.post('/process', parseForm, function (req, res) {
  res.send('data is being processed')
});

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

How can the API be secured using either the auth token or via the csrf tokens?

Comment: Hey buddy did you find a solution?

Comment: @1nstinct, sorry, the project got closed and I did not get to work in the app / changes

Comment: I think jwt-csrf is what you was looking for. Anyway good luck on new project

Answer (score 0):

please check:
 The call to `app.use(csrf())` must be set after `app.use(cookieParser())` AND app.use`(session({...})`.

Comment: I don't want to use either of them, no cookies and no session. kindly refer the code snippet in the post which does not have either of these middlewares.

Comment: **csrf**Requires either a session middleware or cookie-parser to be initialized first. please check : [ https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf ]

Answer (score 0):

I've got into the same trouble. I don't have neither session nor cookies but JWT tokens. For now I am going to implement CSRF protection with [jwt-csrf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-csrf) module. I think it is totally fit to my need and needs of topic starter.